# Triggering Raspberry Pi GPIO with 127V AC

Tags: circuit-design, raspberry-pi

I'm building a home automation system with raspberry pi and would like to trigger it with a regular pulse switch, connected to my home's 127V AC power network. I'm doing this so I don't need to rewire my power outlets.

I came up with a circuit like this. Do you guys think it would work?

[image]

Thanks!

**Edit 1**: Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The switch is far away from the raspberry and the wiring is already in place, that's why I would like to use 127V.

**Edit 2**: deleted

**Edit 3**: new diagram:

[image]

Comment: Please, can you explain more? What I understand is that you want to interrupt rpi whenever pulse from "pulse switch" would cross trough 0 Volts. Am I correct?

Comment: You can attach it directly; you will for sure "trigger" it, at least once... (note: DON'T do it... the "at least once" part means it will blow up in a "not so nice" way)

Comment: @frarugi87 are you serious! its 127 volts (RMS)!

Comment: @Sanmvegsaini I modified the comment... It was intended to be a joke, but I noticed it could be a bit dangerous... I'm also writing a proper answer..

Comment: I think what you are describing is basically a 'Zero Crossing Detector' I'm not really sure why you would want to monitor that from a Raspberry Pi but fair enough. These are normally Opto-isolated from the logic level this is highly recommended for safety and stuff! Could you describe why you want to do this it might help us suggest something more useful. EDIT - Do not connect the circuit you drew up to a Pi It does not look safe!

Comment: We need a lot more details about what you are really trying to accomplish.  Do not build your current circuit, it is inherently unsafe and won't do anything useful.

Comment: No it won't work even if the AC supply was perfectly safe.

Comment: I'm trying to make a button. This button would trigger a relay, for example. I'm aware there are a lot of potential issues with my idea, that's why I'm looking for help.

Comment: Edited the post for clarity.

Comment: Use an optocouple, for the love of god!

Comment: what is a pulse switch? ... the picture shows an on/off toggle switch

Comment: The 50k resistor might easily flashover with a 6kV transient rated for 500V and get rather warm.

Comment: @jsotola Imagine it's a pulse switch

Comment: @Janka Can you please provide some input on my optocouple design?

Comment: Connect the GPIO to the collector of the optocoupler transistor and make R1 10kΩ. Connect an antiparallel 1N4148 across Pin 1 and 2 of the optocoupler. Short R2 and R5, and drop R4. Use an optocoupler with a high CTR and calculate R3 so the current through the diodes is 2mA.

Comment: @Janka, thanks, updated with your suggestions. The problem of moving the GPIO to the collector is that this makes it 1 when the optocoupler is disabled. Also, I'm using different grounds for the left and right side, so I didn't join them.

Comment: @AlexandreGiuseppe usually I tend to use internal pullups or pulldowns, rather than external ones. In any case this is not an issue. Regarding the inversion of the value, it is not an issue (you will need to invert it in SW); anyway it does not change for optocouplers, so you can leave them this way

Comment: @frarugi87 Do you think adding a ceramic capacitor parallel to the diodes will add some protection for the optocoupler? Any suggestion to make this more robust will be welcome

Comment: Adding an antiparallel 1N4148 is sufficient.

Comment: @AlexandreGiuseppe don't add ceramic capacitors. In this case a capacitor is useless, and please consider that ceramic capacitors are NOT good for high voltage. If you need capacitors on high voltage, check carefully what you can and can't add (e.g. PP capacitors with X2 rating)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the people just use a 1M resistor in series with the power; personally I'd also add a small zener to reduce risks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUQDj8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, personally **I don't like this**. Remember that in this case the ground is tied to the neutral wire, and so the rPI is no more insulated. This is usually a thing I want to avoid with microcontrollers, and much more with a complex system like a rPI which gets attached to a lot of other stuff.

For this reason I highly suggest you to avoid this, and use a proper optocoupler. For instance I have used in the past cheap optocouplers (PC817) to sense the presence of the 230V signal. I suggest you to search for circuits with optocouplers (in my case, I used the optocoupler, a diode to block reverse wave, and 100k resistor(s) to limit the current (in your case you may reduce the value of the resistors). This way high voltage and low voltages are properly separated.

My (slightly different) circuit is in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/391678/sense-230v-voltage) other question, but there are plenty of them. Note: you will have a 50Hz wave there, so you shall filter it either in SW or in HW

Comment: The above circuit is not safe in the event of a failure or arcing, make sure you use an optocoupler for saftey.

Comment: Can you please provide some input on my optocouple design? Thanks.

Comment: Yes :) See also my question and some answers here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31648/gpio-protection-diodes-maximum-input-current